# Isn't it possible to change a template at moqups.com?

Tags: mockup, template-design

After creating a template at moqups.com, I cannot change it.

Have not found any documentation about it at it's web-app.

Does anyone know another option like using a "master" or similar that could be modified.

Comment: Probably better to direct this question to the customer service people at moqups.com.

Comment: Good idea. I'll copy here the answer when received. It may useful for other users.